# Item is created twice in dB

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

**Explanation**

It is a form with many V-Radio-Button that are loaded from the database (optionsDB)

```
options in db:  [{ID: 21, Name: "Cellphones"}, {ID: 32, Name: "Computer",}]].
```

Then the loading component some options from the database that the user may have previously configured, or may not load anything (OrginalOptions)

```
 orginalOptions: [{ID: 1, Inventory_Id: 21, Quantity: 32, Status: 1}, {ID: 2, Inventory_ID: 21, Quantity: 32, Status: 1}]
```

What I do is walk the arrangements to see if the user made a change in any option, checking first if he has inventory_id to send the data to another function that edits the item. So far the program works well.

From here ELSE:

```
   } else {
            if ((allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].state ....
```

Then this is the ELSE, which is for the new items that are configured on the Web and therefore do not have a service assigned from the dB and are not in OrginalOptions [], only exist in AllOps [].

AllOps [] Automatically configures and the status or quantity fields are created depending on what the user modifies (here all well)

```
 allOptions item changed:  [{ID: 37, Name: "itemx", Quantity: 50}]
```

What I try to do in This step is to check the changes is the variables "Quantity" and "State" for this way send the data to the DB and create them. (This would put the item in orginalopions [])

**The problem in all this is that the item is created twice in the database**

```
 alloption[] a future..
 [{ID: 3, Inventory_Id: 37, status: 1, Quantity: 50}]
 [{ID: 4, Inventory_Id: 37, status: 1, Quantity: 50}]
```

I think the problem is for the for-in loops.
The program does not have how to check if item was already added ..
Thanks.

```
    async saveInventarioItemsUser () {
          let self = this
          let itemsToDb = []
          let allOptions = self.items_config_inventario
          let orginalOptions = self.items_config_inventario_original
          for (let indexOpcionesUsuarioOriginal in orginalOptions) {
            for (let indexOpcionesTablas in allOptions) {
              if (allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].inventario) {
                if (orginalOptions[indexOpcionesUsuarioOriginal].inventario === allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].inventario) {
                  if (allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].cantidad !== orginalOptions[indexOpcionesUsuarioOriginal].cantidad || allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].state !== orginalOptions[indexOpcionesUsuarioOriginal].state) {
                    let inventario = {
                      orden_trabajo: self.$route.params.editar,
                      inventario: allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].inventario,
                      cantidad: allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].cantidad,
                      state: allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].state
                    }
                    self.saveIndividualItemInventario(allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].id, inventario)
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log('No coincide con .inventario_id', allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas])
                }
              } else {
                if ((allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].state !== 0 && allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].state > 0) || allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].cantidad >= 1) {
                  console.log('ITEM SIN INVENTARIO, CREAR')
                  console.log('ITEM SIN INVENTARIO, CREAR', allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas])
                  if (itemsToDb.length > 0) {
                    itemsToDb.map(item => {
                      if (item.id === allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].id) {
                        console.log('ITEM EN ARRAY', allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas])
                        let data = {
                          orden_trabajo: self.$route.params.editar,
                          inventario: allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].id,
                          cantidad: allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].cantidad || 1,
                          state: allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas].state || 1
                        }
                        self.pushDBNewOpt(data)
                      } else {
                        console.log('PUSH ITEM')
                        itemsToDb.push(allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas])
                        console.log('PUSH ITEM', itemsToDb)
                      }
                    })
                  } else {
                    console.log('PUSH ITEM ELSE')
                    itemsToDb.push(allOptions[indexOpcionesTablas])
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          itemsToDb = []
        }
```

pushDBNewOpt

```
async pushDBNewOpt (data) {
  let self = this
  await self._create(`endpoint/item/`, data, (response) => {
    console.log('RESP saveInventarioItemsUser', response)
    self.loadInventarioItemsUser()
  })
},
```

Comment: why is `saveInventarioItemsUser` and `async` function since it never uses `await`? That usually shows a design flaw for a start - as does `let self = this` ... since there's one single function in that code, and it's an arrow function, therefore you don't need that old school cruft :p

Comment: how should I use it in that case, the truth is something nobo

Comment: how should you use what? what are you making and `async` function that never uses `await`? is there some call in that function that should be awaited? if not, then don't async, if so, then await